# Revert SVN repo to sparse checkout (undo 'svn up --set-depth infinity')?

Tags: svn, depth

Is it possible to revert an SVN working copy to a sparse checkout?

I have a sparse checkout of a very large repository. I ran `svn up --set-depth infinity` on one of the subfolders, but this has resulted in checking out many, many files that I do not want. If I could wind back time I would do instead `svn up --set-depth immediates` in the subfolder, and then do that recursively only in the subfolders I care about (rather than the whole sub-tree).

I have no changes I need to keep in this sub-tree, so I'm happy to do fairly destructive things to recover it. However I do have changes in a different sub-tree, so I'd rather not just throw away the whole working copy. Is there a way (or a hack) I can just delete the sub-tree and then tell SVN to update only to depth `immediates`?

Comment: What's wrong with doing another `svn up --set-depth immediates` on that subfolder?

Comment: @Ben - I thought that wasn't possible, though I'm not sure why (and may just be wrong). I've just kicked off that command and will see what happens (right now it's just hung with no output; I'm not sure how long I'll wait to see if it's working, but the original `--set-depth infinity` update took nearly 3 hours, so it might take a while.

Comment: @Ben - yes, this works, thankyou. I actually cancelled the command I was running and re-tried it further down the tree (so it completed more quickly & I could check it was working) - previously the command just appeared to be hung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Ben's comment, you can undo this by just running `svn up --set-depth immediates`.

Note this can take a long time if the checkout is very large!

[Updated:] After the command has finished, you then need to delete all the extra files that were checked out (`--set-depth` does not delete them).